# How to find who's dropping the connection?

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

When an IP address is accessible by one machine on one ISP but not another machine/ISP, how can you determine where along the path the issue lies?

Is it possible to determine whether it's the destination IP address/host who's the culprit, or the ISP, or some routing node along the way?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `pathping ipaddress` from each computer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows:

From the command line, on each computer, run 'tracert youripaddress' to see if the destination is reachable.

Comment: or pathping which is the same and with pinging.

Comment: Aggredo. 6 of one, half-dozen of the other for this I should think.

Comment: Pathping gives more useful info, for example how packets are being lost/dropped

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Interesting, had never heard of pathping. I've used and tried tracert, however, the destination isn't reachable -- there are 10+ entries of "No response" up until the end.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm assuming these commands basically show which node along the line is causing the problem? But sometimes nodes don't respond to the trace, even though they're working correctly, right? How can you tell whether a node is simply not providing info for the trace vs. not working entirely (or dropping the connection/packet)?

Comment: @Coldblackice Too long an answer for a comment ... but you can tell the difference from the `pathping` output.

Comment: @Coldblackice See https://technet.microsoft.com/library/Cc958876 for the long answer.  If you provide the `pathping` output I will analyse it for you ;)

Comment: @Coldblackice Summary: "The loss rates displayed for the links (marked as a "|" in the rightmost column) indicate losses of packets being forwarded along the path. This loss indicates link congestion. The loss rates displayed for routers (indicated by their IP addresses in the rightmost column) indicate that those routers' CPUs or packet buffers might be overloaded. These congested routers might also be a factor in end-to-end problems, especially if packets are forwarded by software routers."